# Can Google drive file.insert check before insert, to prevent creating a duplicate folder?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

Is there any way to stop creating duplicate folders in google drive with [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) without looping all the items and compare their title with the folder name.

Also How can I list all the folders of root folder.

I have tried to pass the folder id "root" as an argument in list files and list children method but not getting the expected response.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the Related Section? Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

[Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)'s job is to simply create a new file.  It is up to you to check if that file or directory exists before trying to create a new one.

You might want to check out [Files: List](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) by using the [q](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters) option you can have the api do the search for you.   If it returns anything your directory already exists you shouldn't insert it.   Good thing about this is it will also return the file id allowing you to use it in later requests.

> mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
>   title contains 'hello' and title contains 'goodbye'